# How to view each one method to print the output values?

Tags: python, signals, mean, generalized-method-of-moments

```
#from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean

import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.signal

def matrix_from_csv_file(file_path):
    """
    Returns the data matrix given the path of a CSV file.
    
    Parameters:
        file_path (str): path for the CSV file with a time stamp in the first column
            and the signals in the subsequent ones.
            Time stamps are in seconds, with millisecond precision
    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray: 2D matrix containing the data read from the CSV
    
    Author: 
        Original: [lmanso] 
        Revision and documentation: [fcampelo]
    
    """
    
    csv_data = np.genfromtxt(file_path, delimiter = ',')
    full_matrix = csv_data[1:]
    #headers = csv_data[0] # Commented since not used or returned [fcampelo]
    
    return full_matrix


def get_time_slice(full_matrix, start = 0., period = 1.):
    """
    Returns a slice of the given matrix, where start is the offset and period is 
    used to specify the length of the signal.
    
    Parameters:
        full_matrix (numpy.ndarray): matrix returned by matrix_from_csv()
        start (float): start point (in seconds after the beginning of records) 
        period (float): duration of the slice to be extracted (in seconds)
    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray: 2D matrix with the desired slice of the matrix
        float: actual length of the resulting time slice
        
    Author:
        Original: [lmanso]
        Reimplemented: [fcampelo]
    """
    
    # Changed for greater efficiency [fcampelo]
    rstart  = full_matrix[0, 0] + start
    index_0 = np.max(np.where(full_matrix[:, 0] <= rstart))
    index_1 = np.max(np.where(full_matrix[:, 0] <= rstart + period))
    
    duration = full_matrix[index_1, 0] - full_matrix[index_0, 0]
    return full_matrix[index_0:index_1, :], duration


def feature_mean(matrix):
    """
    Returns the mean value of each signal for the full time window
    
    Parameters:
        matrix (numpy.ndarray): 2D [nsamples x nsignals] matrix containing the 
        values of nsignals for a time window of length nsamples
        
    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray: 1D array containing the means of each column from the input matrix
        list: list containing feature names for the quantities calculated.
    Author:
        Original: [lmanso]
        Revision and documentation: [fcampelo]
    """
    
    ret = np.mean(matrix, axis = 0).flatten()
    names = ['mean_' + str(i) for i in range(matrix.shape[1])]
    return ret, names



def feature_mean_d(h1, h2):
    """
    Computes the change in the means (backward difference) of all signals 
    between the first and second half-windows, mean(h2) - mean(h1)
    
    Parameters:
        h1 (numpy.ndarray): 2D matrix containing the signals for the first 
        half-window
        h2 (numpy.ndarray): 2D matrix containing the signals for the second 
        half-window
        
    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray: 1D array containing the difference between the mean in h2 
        and the mean in h1 of all signals
        list: list containing feature names for the quantities calculated.
    Author:
        Original: [lmanso]
        Revision and documentation: [fcampelo]
    
    """
    ret = (feature_mean(h2)[0] - feature_mean(h1)[0]).flatten()
    
    
    # Fixed naming [fcampelo]
    names = ['mean_d_h2h1_' + str(i) for i in range(h1.shape[1])]
    return ret, names



def feature_mean_q(q1, q2, q3, q4):
    """
    Computes the mean values of each signal for each quarter-window, plus the 
    paired differences of means of each signal for the quarter-windows, i.e.,
    feature_mean(q1), feature_mean(q2), feature_mean(q3), feature_mean(q4),
    (feature_mean(q1) - feature_mean(q2)), (feature_mean(q1) - feature_mean(q3)),
    ...
    
    Parameters:
        q1 (numpy.ndarray): 2D matrix containing the signals for the first 
        quarter-window
        q2 (numpy.ndarray): 2D matrix containing the signals for the second 
        quarter-window
        q3 (numpy.ndarray): 2D matrix containing the signals for the third 
        quarter-window
        q4 (numpy.ndarray): 2D matrix containing the signals for the fourth 
        quarter-window
        
    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray: 1D array containing the means of each signal in q1, q2, 
        q3 and q4; plus the paired differences of the means of each signal on 
        each quarter-window.
        list: list containing feature names for the quantities calculated.
    Author:
        Original: [lmanso]
        Revision and documentation: [fcampelo]
    
    """
    v1 = feature_mean(q1)[0]
    v2 = feature_mean(q2)[0]
    v3 = feature_mean(q3)[0]
    v4 = feature_mean(q4)[0]
    ret = np.hstack([v1, v2, v3, v4, 
                     v1 - v2, v1 - v3, v1 - v4, 
                     v2 - v3, v2 - v4, v3 - v4]).flatten()
    
    
    # Fixed naming [fcampelo]
    names = []
    for i in range(4): # for all quarter-windows
        names.extend(['mean_q' + str(i + 1) + "_" + str(j) for j in range(len(v1))])
    
    for i in range(3): # for quarter-windows 1-3
        for j in range((i + 1), 4): # and quarter-windows (i+1)-4
            names.extend(['mean_d_q' + str(i + 1) + 'q' + str(j + 1) + "_" + str(k) for k in range(len(v1))])
             
    return ret, names




def feature_stddev(matrix):
    """
    Computes the standard deviation of each signal for the full time window
    
    Parameters:
        matrix (numpy.ndarray): 2D [nsamples x nsignals] matrix containing the 
        values of nsignals for a time window of length nsamples
        
    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray: 1D array containing the standard deviation of each column 
        from the input matrix
        list: list containing feature names for the quantities calculated.
    Author:
        Original: [lmanso]
        Revision and documentation: [fcampelo]
    """
    
    # fix ddof for finite sampling correction (N-1 instead of N in denominator)
    ret = np.std(matrix, axis = 0, ddof = 1).flatten()
    names = ['std_' + str(i) for i in range(matrix.shape[1])]
    
    return ret, names



def feature_stddev_d(h1, h2):
    """
    Computes the change in the standard deviations (backward difference) of all 
    signals between the first and second half-windows, std(h2) - std(h1)
    
    Parameters:
        h1 (numpy.ndarray): 2D matrix containing the signals for the first 
        half-window
        h2 (numpy.ndarray): 2D matrix containing the signals for the second 
        half-window
        
    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray: 1D array containing the difference between the stdev in h2 
        and the stdev in h1 of all signals
        list: list containing feature names for the quantities calculated.
    Author:
        Original: [lmanso]
        Revision and documentation: [fcampelo]
    
    """
    
    ret = (feature_stddev(h2)[0] - feature_stddev(h1)[0]).flatten()
    
    # Fixed naming [fcampelo]
    names = ['std_d_h2h1_' + str(i) for i in range(h1.shape[1])]
    
    return ret, names




def feature_moments(matrix):
    """
    Computes the 3rd and 4th standardised moments about the mean (i.e., skewness 
    and kurtosis) of each signal, for the full time window. Notice that 
    scipy.stats.moments() returns the CENTRAL moments, which need to be 
    standardised to compute skewness and kurtosis.
    Notice: Kurtosis is calculated as excess kurtosis, e.g., with the Gaussian 
    kurtosis set as the zero point (Fisher's definition)
    - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kurtosis.html
    - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skew.html
    - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardized_moment
    - http://www.econ.nyu.edu/user/ramseyj/textbook/pg93.99.pdf
    
    Parameters:
        matrix (numpy.ndarray): 2D [nsamples x nsignals] matrix containing the 
        values of nsignals for a time window of length nsamples
        
    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray: 1D array containing the skewness and kurtosis of each 
        column from the input matrix
        list: list containing feature names for the quantities calculated.
    Author:
        Original: [fcampelo]
    """

    skw = scipy.stats.skew(matrix, axis = 0, bias = False)
    krt = scipy.stats.kurtosis(matrix, axis = 0, bias = False)
    ret  = np.append(skw, krt)
        
    names = ['skew_' + str(i) for i in range(matrix.shape[1])]
    names.extend(['kurt_' + str(i) for i in range(matrix.shape[1])])
    return ret, names
```

Comment: This is just a wall of code. What do you want to do?

Comment: In each method of process i want to know the output of each values of data

Comment: ..but that is already stated in the headers: e.g. `numpy.ndarray: 2D matrix containing the data read from the CSV`

Comment: Output is not printed how  can i do

Comment: I don't want CSV files